# Include in included file doesn't work PHP

Tags: php, function, include

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

I have the following html list:

```
<ul id="ulGroups">
<?php
include('organizer_picturearchive_groups.php');
?>
</ul>
```

I am trying to include this file, which also includes another file:

```
<?php
include('lib/organizer_functions/picture_archive.php');
    echo select_all_picture_category_groups();
?>
```

Basically, what I am trying to do is to call a function that is in the picture_archive.php file. I do that in the organizer_picturearchive_groups.php file.
I am including this file in the first file where the html list is. I am not pasting the whole code from there, because it is a lot, but it works.

However the include thing doesn't, because when I tried to make a test echo statement in the "organizer_picturearchive_groups.php" file it works and I can see the text I am printing.

Do you have ideas what may cause this problem ?

Comment: There is no error. Just nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check the path. If `organizer_picturearchive_groups.php` is in the same directory as the code, then try configuring the path as relative:

```
<?php
include('./organizer_picturearchive_groups.php');
?>
```

Comment: I did that as you said, but now even the echo statement doesn't work. Still no errors. So, I guess the problem is with the other file:
"organizer_picturearchive_groups.php"

Comment: Post both complete files to pastebin, I'll take a look.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but actually I just fixed it and it works. But I couldn't understand where the problem was. I think it is because of the include statement and because I have some other includes in another files and maybe it makes conflicts or something...I am still new to PHP and and don't even know the syntax  and so on. But I had this task..
Thank you all for the help!

Comment: @Apostrofix I'm working with a legacy Wordpress site and am running into this same issue. I guess it's been 5 years, but if you remember your solution...

Comment: @kauffee000 I can't exactly remember but my html file was including other php files which were including even more files. So there was a mistake somewhere either in the paths or with an incorrect include statement in one of those files. Double check your paths and names.

Comment: @Apostrofix oh it didn't even occur to me that the child template might need to use a path relative to the parent. I'll give that a go, thanks.